# DriveApp vs SpreadsheetApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Apps Script, I see some functions are common to DriveApp and SpreadsheetApp. I am able to achieve the desired result using either one. What are the pros and cons of choosing one over the other? Any benefits of performance, efficiency etc?

Edit per @Ruben's advice: 
I was thinking specifically of commands like DriveApp.getFileById(id) vs SpreadsheetApp.openById(id), which appear to have similar function.

Comment: Are there any specific functions you are talking about? Or is my general answer okay?

Comment: What functions do you find that are common to DriveApp and SpreadsheetApp?

Comment: @Rubén I was thinking of commands like  DriveApp.getFileById(id) vs SpreadsheetApp.openById(id), which appeared similar at first glance. Chris' message below clarifies the difference to me.

Comment: In order to make your question look better and probably well received by the community, add those details to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**They are actually quite different.**

In general, [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) deals with all files existing on a users drive. It's functions returns [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file.html), [Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder.html), [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator.html), and [FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator.html) Objects. With these types you can not (mostly) modify the contents of the files with the functions that SpreadsheetApp, DocumentApp, etc would give you. They let you move and copy files around the Drive.

[SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) deals with [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html), [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet.html), and [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html) Objects. These give you much **finer control** of pulling and modifying data within the files.

> *It's like the difference between moving/copying/pasting/attaching a file on your desktop or opening it to change content.*

As for the function that are similar between them, they are about the same, but might have a slightly different result, so check the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was looking at commands like DriveApp.getFileById(id) vs SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).

At first glance, both seem to do the same thing.  The highlighted section in your response clarifies it... use DriveApp.getFilebyId(id) if I want to get the file to move it to a different folder, for example. But if I actually want to modify its contents, I need to use SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).